# Changing anchor tag text while using PhoneGap and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

As a preface, I am using PhoneGap. When I click on a Category Title, I have taken that title and set it in sessionStorage. Now, I want to set the "back" button of a new PhoneGap page (which displays some information contained in that category) to that Category Title. The HTML code is shown below. To be specific, I want to change the text of the "a" element within the "header" element.

I guess a part of my question is, does the fact that I am using PhoneGap change how I can access the anchor tag? I've been trying to set the back button text right after the Category has been selected/clicked on. I have tried multiple things like:

```
$("adviceBodyNavbarHeader a").text(sessionStorage.getItem("catTitle"));
```

but I can't quite get it working, and it is getting quite frustrating =/

```
<div data-role="view" id="adviceBody" data-title="Advice Body" data-show="GetAdviceBody" data-transition="slide">
    <header data-role="header" id="adviceBodyNavbarHeader">
        <div class="navHeader">
            <a class="nav-button" data-view="adviceTitles" data-align="left">Back</a>
            <span id="adviceTitle" class="navTitle"></span>
        </div>
    </header>
    <ul id="advice-body" data-role="listview">
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector is wrong. You try to select a html element called `adviceBodyNavbarHeader`.

What you want to do is this: `$('#adviceBodyNavbarHeader').text(sessionStorage.getItem("catTitle"));`

Hope it helps.

Edited my post due to late brain inactivity.

Comment: Oh my gosh I KNEW it was something small and stupid. The tunnel vision is overwhelming. Thanks for being my rubber ducky :)